# Which gotoxy() function should I use?

Tags: c

during this year in school my teacher showed us this function:

```
#include<Windows.h>
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    COORD punto;punto.X=x;punto.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),punto);
}
```

And looking in here some posts I read about this one based on ANSI escape codes

```
#include<stdio.h>
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    // <ESC>[(ROW);(COLUMN)f
    printf("\x1B[%i;%if",y,x);
}
```

I kind of like the second one more, I feel I understand it better. But I wanted to ask here which of them is better because I know I'm probably missing something. What do you think?

Comment: If you're only ever targeting a specific framework (in this case the Windows API), it's probably better to use that. (And I say that as someone who gets irrationally annoyed every time they read Windows-targetting C) It's very clear what's happening in the first case. The second one is confusing, and you'd have to be sure that the escape codes are supported in the environment where you're running the program. It depends entirely on the program's aim.

Comment: Which did you try? In my Windows console, the first works and the second does not. If you are not in Windows the first one will not work. It depends on the system you are running on.

Comment: Can anyone explain `printf("\x1B[%i;%if",y,x);`?

Comment: There's also `#include <curses.h>` ... `move(y, x);` to do things more portably.

Comment: The second one is better. It's more portable and it *does* work in Windows and DOS if you use `ansi.sys`.

Comment: @Ayxan You can look into ANSI escape codes. I wrote a note on top of if that explains the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write code for Windows then definitely use the first version. It always works on Windows but it does not work on other OSes (it does not even compile because other OSes do not provide these functions).

The second version is not tight to an OS. It works on any OS as long as the application runs in a terminal emulator that understands [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (most of them do).